# why action asking me about two parameters when im using form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, routes

why when im trying to send this three params(recipients_emails) I get error:

> ArgumentError in FreeRegistrationCouponsController#send
>
> wrong number of arguments (2 for 0) Rails.root:
>   /Users/regedarek/code/wifiname
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/controllers/free_registration_coupons_controller.rbin `send'

What Im doing wrong?

```
<div class="span6">
  <b>Give three of your friends a free registration</b>
  <%= form_tag :controller => 'free_registration_coupons', :action => "send" do %>
    <%= label_tag :recipient_email_1 %>
    <%= text_field_tag :recipient_email_1 %>
    <%= label_tag :recipient_email_2 %>
    <%= text_field_tag :recipient_email_2 %>
    <%= label_tag :recipient_email_3 %>
    <%= text_field_tag :recipient_email_3 %>
    <%= submit_tag %>
  <% end %>
</div>

class FreeRegistrationCouponsController < ApplicationController
  def send
    @sender_id = current_user.id

    binding.pry
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end

resources :free_registration_coupons do
  collection do
    get 'send'
    post 'send'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call your action send - you're overwriting a core ruby method. Rails is trying to call this core ruby method, but ends up calling your method instead, which has a different signature.

Rails should probably be using `__send__` so that you are free to use `send` for your own purposes, but there's not much you can do about that right now.

Comment: This is interesting -- can you point to any information on not being able name an action `send`?

Comment: Well the core ruby method is documented [http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send](here) and if you look at the rails source you can see it using send. There used to be a (vaguely) maintained list of 'bad' action/model/method/class names but I don't think there is an up to date one at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your form to read like this:

```
<div class="span6">
  <b>Give three of your friends a free registration</b>
  <%= form_tag '/free_registration_coupons/send' do %>
    <%= label_tag :recipient_email_1 %>
    <%= text_field_tag :recipient_email_1 %>
    <%= label_tag :recipient_email_2 %>
    <%= text_field_tag :recipient_email_2 %>
    <%= label_tag :recipient_email_3 %>
    <%= text_field_tag :recipient_email_3 %>
    <%= submit_tag %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I believe the issue is that your form_tag isn't expecting the arguments the way you've included them.